# tellp is returning the wrong value

Tags: c++

In the following snipped, I am calculating a position for a file to seekp to, for writing.

I then try to print that position. It is returning an incorrect value;

```
printf("nXBlocks: %i nYBlocks: %i posX: %i, posY: %i, blockheight: %i, blockwidth: %i \n", 
nXBlocks,nYBlocks, tilePosX,  tilePosY ,  XBlockSize, YBlockSize );
binfile->seekp((tilePosX*poBand->GetYSize()*XBlockSize)*sizeof(uint16_t) + (tilePosY * XBlockSize*YBlockSize)*sizeof(uint16_t));
size_t pos = binfile->tellp();
cout<<"Multiplication output: " 
    <<(tilePosX*poBand->GetYSize()*XBlockSize)*sizeof(uint16_t) + (tilePosY * XBlockSize*YBlockSize)*sizeof(uint16_t)
    <<endl;
cout << "Put pointer positions: " << pos << endl;
binfile->write((char *)&sixteenBitData, sizeof(uint16_t)*bufSizeX*bufSizeY);
```

I am getting a output of

Put pointer position: 18446744073709551615

For every call to the tellp

Instead of values based on the values I am passing to seekp

edit: some output of the first few...

```
nXBlocks: 34 nYBlocks: 29 posX: 0, posY: 0, blockheight: 1024, blockwidth: 1024
Multiplication output: 0
Put pointer positions: 0
nXBlocks: 34 nYBlocks: 29 posX: 0, posY: 1, blockheight: 1024, blockwidth: 1024
Multiplication output: 2097152
Put pointer positions: 18446744073709551615
nXBlocks: 34 nYBlocks: 29 posX: 0, posY: 2, blockheight: 1024, blockwidth: 1024
Multiplication output: 4194304
Put pointer positions: 18446744073709551615
```

Comment: Is the file opened as binary?

Comment: Since this is C++ question use the std::cout to print. Then you will be guaranteed to get the correct type when printing. Rather than using "zu" whch seems to be a C99 extension to the formatting.

Comment: I just updated it to use the cout syntax instead, and added some output

Comment: 18446744073709551615 == 0x1999999999999999, nice round number.

Comment: 18446744073709551615 is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, also known as -1.

Comment: @Hans, you omitted the final digit of the decimal number when you did your conversion.

Answer (score 0):

seekp is apparently failing.  It's likely that you are trying to seek to a point not in the file.  Try getting the value

```
binfile.bad()
```